# Reinitialise React component without forcing remount

Tags: reactjs

In React, how, if at all, can I reinitialise a component without forcing a remount?

I have some parent state, which is passed as props to the child. Whenever that state changes, I want to have a completely fresh instance of the component. I.e. state should be reset, but also any properties (`this.property = value;`) that I set on the component. This can easily be achieved by setting the prop also as a key on the child. However, that also causes the child to remount, even though the VDOM is the same.

It seems to me that there is no technical reason why it should not be possible to initialise a new component, but then diff the created VDOM against the old VDOM and decide not to remount. Is this possible with React?

Comment: "that also causes the child to remount, even though the VDOM is the same." - how is the virtual dom is same if the props changes ?

Comment: @Dilshan the child has some internal state. in the initial state, the prop is irrelevant, but once the user interacts with the component it behaves differently based on the value of the prop.